# JNA: Computed size of char array member of a struct is surprising

Tags: java, c, jna

Can someone explain to me why the following structure size is 16 ?

```java
public class StringStruct extends Structure {
  public char[] data = new char[4];

  public StringStruct() {}

  @Override
  protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
    return Collections.singletonList("data");
  }
}



public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    StringStruct ss = new StringStruct();

    // Prints StringStruct: 16
    // I was expecting 4...
    System.out.println("StringStruct: " + ss.size());

  }

}
```

I want to model structures which *own* their data

```c
typedef struct {
   char data[4];
} StringStruct_s
```

If I use a byte array instead, it returns the expected value. Still, the char array size is really surprising to me. Is the field interpreted as owning an encoded String ?
So, I launched this executable with various explicit encodings (`-Djna.encoding="..."`) to see if it had an effect. No change...

Comment: What does the java char datatype mean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `JNA`, Java char can be mapped to either `16-bit` or `32-bit` character.

It means that you have: `32/8 * 4 = 16`

https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/Mappings.md

Try something like this on your machine

```
int main() {
  printf("%ld\n",sizeof(wchar_t));
}
```

**Update**

As mentioned by @Daniel, it's worth noting that mapping `C` based `char` should be done via `byte`.

For this class

```
interface CLibrary extends Library {

  public CLibrary.Data.ByVal GetDataValue();
  public CLibrary.Data.ByRef GetDataAllocated();

  public class Data extends Structure {

    public static final List<String> FIELDS =  List.of("array");

    public static class ByVal extends Data implements Structure.ByValue {}

    public static class ByRef extends Data implements Structure.ByReference {}

    public byte[] array = new byte[4];

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
      return FIELDS;
    }
  }
}
```

you will get size as expected: `4`

Comment: Somehow, I missed this in the documentation. Thank you !

Comment: While this is correct, I don't think you're addressing the root cause of the OP's problem.  They are attempting to map a C structure with a `char[]` type, and the correct mapping is to use `byte[]`.   I think your answer would be improved if you highlighted the correct mapping in addition to explaining why they got the incorrect results.