# why char[1024] shallow size is 2072

Tags: java, java-8, jvm

[image]Here is a char array with length 1024. I dump Java program run in Java8 into a hprof file. I find the size of char[1024] is 2072.

In my opinion, empty char array takes header(8 bytes) plus reference(4 bytes) plus length(int 4 bytes). So size of empty char array is 16 bytes.

So total size of char[1024] should be `1024 * 2 + 16 = 2064` bytes.

I use Java 1.8 and run in jvm 1.8.0_333

Comment: possible duplicate of [JNA: Computed size of char array member of a struct is surprising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57843556/jna-computed-size-of-char-array-member-of-a-struct-is-surprising)

Comment: [What Heap Dumps Are Lying To You About](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/heapdump-is-a-lie/)